# How to ajax in spring mvc and tile

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, tile

Is there any way integrate ajax in spring mvc and apache tile. For me, when sent the request to controller and after that send back to view, the data can not pass through tile config.
Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time.  What i do is, instead of sending back a "View" string or "ModelAndView" object, return an object of type ResponseEntity.

For instance, in your controller class, you can have a method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cache/clear", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> clearAllCaches() {
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    long startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (CachingService cachingService : cachingServices) {
        LOGGER.info("Clearing caches in " + cachingService.getClass().getSimpleName());
        cachingService.clearCache();
    }
    long finishTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long executionTime = finishTimestamp - startTimestamp;
    LOGGER.warn("Finished clearing caches in " + cachingServices.size() + " services in " + executionTime + " ms.");
    results.put("executionTime", executionTime);
    results.put("serviceCount", cachingServices.size());
    results.put(ServiceConstants.RETURN_KEY_SUCCESS, Boolean.TRUE);
    return createResponse(results, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

protected ResponseEntity<String> createResponse(Map <String, Object> results, HttpStatus successCode) {
    JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
    String responseBody = serializer.deepSerialize(results);
    HttpStatus status = successCode;
    boolean success = results.containsKey(ServiceConstants.RETURN_KEY_SUCCESS) 
                          ? (Boolean)results.get(ServiceConstants.RETURN_KEY_SUCCESS)
                          : false;
    if (!success) {
        status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setContentLength(responseBody.length());
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseBody, headers, status);
}
```

Note that I'm using FlexJSON as I'm using Spring Roo.  You could also manually invoke Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem by annotation @ResponseBody to send string back to ajax page.

```
public @ResponseBody
String test() {
    List<User> users = userDetailsService.test();
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
    return "1";
}
```